# Remote Images Causing JQuery Slideshow to stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic slideshow that displays images fine when they are local/relative. If I try and load the image from another domain, the image loads and displays fine, but then the gallery will not advance to the next step.

Works:

```
<ul class="slides"> 
<li><img src="img/photos/1.jpg" width="620" height="320" alt="Turrimetta Beach - Dawn" /></li>   
<li><img src="img/photos/2.jpg" width="620" height="320" alt="Turrimetta Beach - Dawn" /></li> 
<li><img src="img/photos/3.jpg" width="620" height="320" alt="Power Station" /></li> 
<li><img src="img/photos/4.jpg" width="620" height="320" alt="Colors of Nature" /></li> 
</ul>
```

Loads first image and then stops:

```
<ul class="slides"> 
    <li><img src="http://www.alfajango.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/rails-remote.jpg"width="620" height="320" alt="Turrimetta Beach - Dawn" /></li> 
    <li><img src="img/photos/2.jpg" width="620" height="320" alt="Turrimetta Beach - Dawn" /></li> 
    <li><img src="img/photos/3.jpg" width="620" height="320" alt="Power Station" /></li> 
    <li><img src="img/photos/4.jpg" width="620" height="320" alt="Colors of Nature" /></li> 
</ul>
```

The Jquery is taken from [Here](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/01/how-to-make-auto-advancing-slideshows/)

```
$(window).load(function(){

// We are listening to the window.load event, so we can be sure
// that the images in the slideshow are loaded properly.


// Testing wether the current browser supports the canvas element:
var supportCanvas = 'getContext' in document.createElement('canvas');

// The canvas manipulations of the images are CPU intensive,
// this is why we are using setTimeout to make them asynchronous
// and improve the responsiveness of the page.

var slides = $('#slideshow li'),
    current = 0,
    slideshow = {width:0,height:0};

setTimeout(function(){

    window.console && window.console.time && console.time('Generated In');

    if(supportCanvas){
        $('#slideshow img').each(function(){

            if(!slideshow.width){
                // Taking the dimensions of the first image:
                slideshow.width = this.width;
                slideshow.height = this.height;
            }

            // Rendering the modified versions of the images:
            createCanvasOverlay(this);
        });
    }

    window.console && window.console.timeEnd && console.timeEnd('Generated In');

    $('#slideshow .arrow').click(function(){
        var li          = slides.eq(current),
            canvas      = li.find('canvas'),
            nextIndex   = 0;

        // Depending on whether this is the next or previous
        // arrow, calculate the index of the next slide accordingly.

        if($(this).hasClass('next')){
            nextIndex = current >= slides.length-1 ? 0 : current+1;
        }
        else {
            nextIndex = current <= 0 ? slides.length-1 : current-1;
        }

        var next = slides.eq(nextIndex);

        if(supportCanvas){

            // This browser supports canvas, fade it into view:

            canvas.fadeIn(function(){

                // Show the next slide below the current one:
                next.show();
                current = nextIndex;

                // Fade the current slide out of view:
                li.fadeOut(function(){
                    li.removeClass('slideActive');
                    canvas.hide();
                    next.addClass('slideActive');
                });
            });
        }
        else {

            // This browser does not support canvas.
            // Use the plain version of the slideshow.

            current=nextIndex;
            next.addClass('slideActive').show();
            li.removeClass('slideActive').hide();
        }
    });

},100);

// This function takes an image and renders
// a version of it similar to the Overlay blending
// mode in Photoshop.

function createCanvasOverlay(image){

    var canvas          = document.createElement('canvas'),
        canvasContext   = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Make it the same size as the image
    canvas.width = slideshow.width;
    canvas.height = slideshow.height;

    // Drawing the default version of the image on the canvas:
    canvasContext.drawImage(image,0,0);


    // Taking the image data and storing it in the imageData array:
    var imageData   = canvasContext.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height),
        data        = imageData.data;

    // Loop through all the pixels in the imageData array, and modify
    // the red, green, and blue color values.

    for(var i = 0,z=data.length;i<z;i++){

        // The values for red, green and blue are consecutive elements
        // in the imageData array. We modify the three of them at once:

        data[i] = ((data[i] < 128) ? (2*data[i]*data[i] / 255) : (255 - 2 * (255 - data[i]) * (255 - data[i]) / 255));
        data[++i] = ((data[i] < 128) ? (2*data[i]*data[i] / 255) : (255 - 2 * (255 - data[i]) * (255 - data[i]) / 255));
        data[++i] = ((data[i] < 128) ? (2*data[i]*data[i] / 255) : (255 - 2 * (255 - data[i]) * (255 - data[i]) / 255));

        // After the RGB elements is the alpha value, but we leave it the same.
        ++i;
    }

    // Putting the modified imageData back to the canvas.
    canvasContext.putImageData(imageData,0,0);

    // Inserting the canvas in the DOM, before the image:
    image.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas,image);
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only guess is that it has something to do with:

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

I know it's not ideal, but try replacing the window.load with this document.ready and see what happens:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: Got it in one! Thanks. Any idea for the reasoning behind this?

Comment: [check out this](http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/)

Comment: Honestly I'm not really sure, but could it be that the external server was just slower, so if you waited long enough the slideshow would eventually behave as expected? You could change it back to window.load and put alert("done loading"); on the very next line and see if it's ever reached with the off-domain images. Could yield a clue. Do note that using document.ready is not ideal for slideshows because it only guarantees that the DOM has loaded, which doesn't include slower-loading media like images. So on a slow connection, it could start scrolling with empty or half-loaded images.